# Selecting features of vector layers based on another vector layer using QGIS?

Tags: qgis, shapefile, polygon, point, line

I am using QGIS 2.12.2. I am using three vector layers (point, polyline and polygon shapefiles) of the region of interest. Any advice in making the selections from one dataset based on the other dataset? What I am trying to do is to select the features of other two layers based on the one layer in QGIS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tools available only allow you to make selections on **one vector layer based on one other layer**. There are a number of tools which allows you to make selections, just to name a few common ones:

---

- Spatial selection

  1. **Spatial Query**

     (*Vector > Spatial Query)*
  2. **Select by location**

     (*Vector > Research Tools > Select by location; Processing Toolbox > Select by location*)

---

- Attribute selection

  1. **Select by attribute**

     (*Processing Toolbox > Select by attribute*)

---

If you type "Select" in the *Processing Toolbox*, you will see additional selection tools:

[image: Processing Toolbox]

Comment: Thanks Joseph for your feedback. However, I noticed that the available tools did not allow such facility. I need to make selections of features of other two layers (polygons and polylines for example) from a point shapefile (say).

Comment: @JibranKhan - I don't think there's an existing tool that allows you to make selections on one layer based on **two layers**. You could **buffer** your line layer with an extremely low buffer distance (e.g. 0.001) so that your line layer becomes another polygon layer; merge these two to create one layer and use this for your selection with your point tool.

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called multiple layer selection.

Plugins > All > Multiple Layer Selection > Install

Comment: To be honest, I found this the most straight forward and fastest way to do it.

Comment: I can't find this plugin from the library. I'm using QGIS 3.10.