# Merging two separate shapefiles into one shapefile

Tags: qgis, shapefile, vector, layers, merge

I have a problem with vector data tools/ merge vector layers using QGIS 2.18.0.

This is the procedure that I took:

I created some polygons on the base of an aerophoto image.
[image]

I merged these polygons into one bigger piece.
[image]

And now I want to merge these two layers into the layer the already exists and is the first one that I created (that one with smaller separate polygons).
My problem is, that after using the function merge vector layers, the result is same as it is in the original photo. The borders between the polygns are still there.

I don't know where I am making the error.

Is there any other option to delete the borders of the polygons, without having to save into a separate shapefile?

Comment: What kind of GIS application are you using?

Comment: Oh I forgot to write that. I am working in QGIS - latest version (2.18.0)

Comment: Thank you guys for correcting my post, I am new to this forum.

Comment: If I understand correctly your question, in order to remove polyon borders you need to use the dissolve command.

Comment: @Rodri yes you are correct, I need to remove borders between polygons, but when I do that, it creates a new layer that is saved separatly and I need that polygon in my original shapefile, so I tried to merge those two shapefiles. But the result was same as original - bnorders were still there

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand your comments correctly, you have already created the the dissolved shape and merged it in with your other dataset, but are still seeing the other polygons that were merged together to create the large, dissolved polygon?

If so, (and assuming you still have the separate layer of the dissolved polygon) all you will need to do is select the polygons that are overlapped by the merged polygon and delete them.  See [Selecting features of vector layers based on another vector layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176372/selecting-features-of-vector-layers-based-on-another-vector-layer-using-qgis) on performing a Select By Location in QGIS.  I am also not very familiar with QGIS, but assume that there is an option to set about using the centroid of your broken out polygons as a selection parameter or selection option.  Make sure that only those polygons that are actually covered by your new polygon are the only ones selected--there are selection options that will grab any polygon that touches the newly merged one.

**since you are new to this and I am not sure that I 100% understand your problem, please, please, please make a backup copy of your shapefile or data table before deleting data**

Comment: thanks for your answer. I had to dellete the polygons on the oryginal file. In the meantime I figured out that changing the collor of the borders to the same one of the polygons gives same **graphic** result (in the attribute table the plygons are still there).