# QGIS 2.18: Generating simple report on spatial objects falling into an area of interest

Tags: qgis, reports

I am looking for a way to generate a simple report from spatial object falling into the selected area of interest. Report would need to be in form of a table which includes all values from the attribute tables of given polygons.

[image: example]

Any ideas how to go around it most effectively?

I tried Reporter plugin in Qgis but it doesn't do the work exactly. Are there any plugins or tools which could achieve the result?

Answer (score 2):

Are the polygons in the same layer? If they are, you could use "Vector->Research tools->Select by Location". If they aren't, you'll need an additional step.

A previous discussion ([Selecting features of vector layers based on another vector layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176372/selecting-features-of-vector-layers-based-on-another-vector-layer-using-qgis)) mentions that there is no functionality for selections of multiple layers at the moment. You could try to merge the two disjoint polygons into one layer (vector > dissolve) and then perform the select by location step. This would give you a new polygon layer with just the polygons that are inside of your selection. From there you can export the attribute table (right-click->"save as"->"MS Office Open XML spreadsheet [XLSX]").

Comment: hej Alex.L thanks for the response, 
Sometimes polygons are in one layer sometimes they are not. 
I like yoúr solution and if it was about doing it manualy step by step I would have followed similar steps but I am looking for some sort of plugin that can do it automatically. 
Reporter plugin by NextGIS is closest but requires some additional coding. In this app you just mark the AOI and it creates reports from all polygon layers inside which is what i need. However the generated reports are not what I am looking for and that is where the coding needs to be done.