# Selecting multiple polygons on different layer based on another polygon using QGIS

Tags: qgis

I am stuck on selecting polygons. I want to choose green and purple polygons inside the outlier polygon. They are all in different layers.

Can you show me a way to choose all these 3 layers and export them using QGIS?

[image]

[Selecting features of vector layers based on another vector layer using QGIS?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/176372/selecting-features-of-vector-layers-based-on-another-vector-layer-using-qgis) does not work for me

Comment: [Extract by location](https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorselection.html?highlight=extract%20location#extract-by-location)

Comment: @BERA: but with « extract by location », you need to use batch, cause you can only work on one layer… as I understand the question, it is to select all the polygons, on all the different layers!

Comment: exactly @katagena I want to select all layers.

Comment: Batch clip using the selected area polygon then merge the results.